# How can I get a SPAN to be inline in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

This is the element in IE8

[image: This is the element in IE8]

This is the element in Firefox

[image: Firefox]

I need the IE version to look like the FF version. How can I style it to do that? The styles are as follows:

```
.simpleTree
{

    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    padding:10px 0 0 20px;

    overflow:auto;
    width: auto;
    height:250px;
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px solid #b7befe;
    border-width:2px 0 1px;
    background:#fff;

}
.simpleTree li
{
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 0 12px;
    line-height: 14px;
}
.simpleTree li span
{
    display:inline;
    clear: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.simpleTree ul
{
    margin:0 0 0 40px; 
    padding:0;
```

EDIT: Response to comment
I added `zoom: 1` - no change
[image]

EDIT: Added HTML code

```
<ul class="simpleTree">

<li class="root">

<ul>
<li class="line">&nbsp;</li><li id="13108" class="folder-close"><img border="0" src="images/spacer.gif" class="trigger" style="float: left;"><span class="text">English Language Arts (0)</span><ul class="ajax"><li class="line">&nbsp;</li><li class="doc-last">{url:?q=arisbrowser/ajax/get_tree&amp;getset=g&amp;vid=10&amp;tid=13108&amp;time=&amp;gs=}</li><li class="line-last"></li></ul>
</li>

<li class="line">&nbsp;</li><li id="13109" class="folder-close"><img border="0" src="images/spacer.gif" class="trigger" style="float: left;"><span class="text">Math (0)</span><ul class="ajax"><li class="line">&nbsp;</li><li class="doc-last">{url:?q=arisbrowser/ajax/get_tree&amp;getset=g&amp;vid=10&amp;tid=13109&amp;time=&amp;gs=}</li><li class="line-last"></li></ul>
</li>

<li class="line">&nbsp;</li><li id="13110" class="folder-close-last"><img border="0" src="images/spacer.gif" class="trigger" style="float: left;"><span class="active">Literacy in History/Social Studies, Science, and Technical Subjects (0)</span><ul class="ajax"><li class="line">&nbsp;</li><li class="doc-last">{url:?q=arisbrowser/ajax/get_tree&amp;getset=g&amp;vid=10&amp;tid=13110&amp;time=&amp;gs=}</li><li class="line-last"></li></ul>
</li><li class="line-last"></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `span` elements are already inline by default...

Comment: It is inline, but it wraps. What I need is for it to not wrap in IE

Comment: Try throwing `zoom:1` on the span and/or ul

Comment: Can you provide the html as the browser sees it and if possible could you replicate the issue with http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZdzT9/3/ - check out the fiddle in IE and FF

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I resolve a word-wrap issue with IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931698/how-can-i-resolve-a-word-wrap-issue-with-ie)

Comment: @Shamoon: Why did you repost the question and attempt to close this one as a dupe of the new one? It doesn't make any sense, was it a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
li span{overflow-x: scroll;white-space: nowrap;}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rc6ck/1/

It appears that the `<ul class="simpleTree">` may be inside of another container. A test page or full HTML that contrains the `<ul>` may help solve the issue.

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZdzT9/4/

It removes the `.d {word-wrap: break-word; }` from the containing div.

OK, so you need that. Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZdzT9/6/

This time `word-wrap: normal` was added to `.simpleTree li {}`

Comment: No dice - still looks the same. I edited again to include more complete HTML

Comment: @Shamoon Hmmm, when I posted my answer all the HTML for the question was not included and I get down voted? No good deed goes unpunished.

Comment: @Shammoon added new fiddle and edited answer. Please try it out.

Comment: @Jen - for other reasons (templating, etc), I can't edit the CSS for .d. What can I do within the UL to fix it?

Comment: @Shamoon I posted another fiddle.

Comment: @jen let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2108/discussion-between-shamoon-and-jen)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how the expand button is styled but try `white-space:nowrap`

Comment: I assume because OP is already using `white-space:nowrap`, it's in the CSS he posted.